Generate predictions for GAM (mgcv) using penalised cubic spline forced through a certain point
I am using MGCV to generate predictions for a GAM using a cubic spline forced through a certain point. I have generated the gam exactly as outlined in this post: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-March/350253.html
However, when I try to predict y for new values of x within the range of the gam, I get this error: Error: variable 'X' was fitted with type "nmatrix.8" but type "numeric" was supplied.
Here is the script I’m using to try to make the predictions:

From the original post

## Fake some data...

library(mgcv)
set.seed(0)
n <- 100
x <- runif(n)*4-1;x <- sort(x);
f <- exp(4*x)/(1+exp(4*x));y <- f+rnorm(100)*0.1;plot(x,y)
dat <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)

## Create a spline basis and penalty, making sure there is a knot
## at the constraint point, (0 here, but could be anywhere)
knots <- data.frame(x=seq(-1,3,length=9)) ## create knots
## set up smoother...
sm <- smoothCon(s(x,k=9,bs="cr"),dat,knots=knots)[[1]]

## 3rd parameter is value of spline at knot location 0,
## set it to 0 by dropping...
X <- sm$X[,-3]        ## spline basis
S <- sm$S[[1]][-3,-3] ## spline penalty
off <- y*0 + .6       ## offset term to force curve through (0, .6)

## fit spline constrained through (0, .6)...
b <- gam(y ~ X - 1 + offset(off),paraPen=list(X=list(S)))
lines(x,predict(b))


To predict:

library(tidyverse)
  
 # Predict values across concentrations within measured range
  x_seq <- seq(-1, 3, length.out = 10000)
  newdata <- data.frame(X = x_seq)

  # Generate the spline basis matrix for the new data
  sm_new <- smoothCon(s(X, k=9, bs="cr"), newdata, knots=knots)[[1]]
  X_new <- sm_new$X[,-3]  # Match the basis matrix structure used in the model
  
  # Create a data frame with the spline basis matrix
  X_new_df <- as.data.frame(X_new)
    
  # Predict the offset term for the new data
  off_new <- y*0 + .6 # Use the same offset as in the original model
  # Combine the new data with the basis matrix and the offset
  predict_data <- cbind(newdata, X_new_df, off_new) %>% 
    rename(off = off_new)

  # Predict values using the GAM
  predictions <- predict(b, newdata = predict_data, se.fit = TRUE)

I have also tried to put the variables required for a function into a list so they can be called as an argument to ‘data’, but this creates a separate issue wherein the matrix (X) is not recognised: Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :  arguments imply differing number of rows: 27, 8 
Here is the adjusted script I use to build this model, which generates the error:
list.dat <- list(y = y, 
                   X = X, 
                   S = S, 
                   off = off)

b <- gam(y ~ X - 1 + offset(off), 
                     data = list.dat, paraPen=list(X=list(S)))


Can you help me generate predictions for y along more values of x than in the original data? I would prefer to give my variables to the model as a list in the data argument, but I am open to other suggestions too.

If you are trying to penalise the parametric terms X, don't you need paraPen = list(X = list(S)) in your model (last code chunk). You are currently using bigX = list(S), but bigX isn't in the model.

Good catch! Sorry, "bigX" was a typo leftover from my working, where I use "bigX' to better differentiate between "X" and "x". I've edited the post to consistently use "X". Sorry for the confusion!

You can now do this directly with s() via its pc argument (for "point constraint"):
library(mgcv)
set.seed(0)
n <- 100
x <- runif(n) * 4 - 1
x <- sort(x)
f <- exp(4 * x) / (1 + exp(4 * x))
y <- f + rnorm(100) * 0.1
dat <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)

m <- gam(y ~ s(x, pc = 0), data = dat, method = "REML")

Then predict() etc works as expected:
library("gratia")

ds <- data_slice(m, x = evenly(x))
fv <- fitted_values(m, data = ds) # calls predict
fv

# A tibble: 100 × 6
    .row      x .fitted    .se .lower_ci .upper_ci
   <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     1 -0.946  0.0364 0.0526  -0.0666      0.140
 2     2 -0.907  0.0375 0.0463  -0.0534      0.128
 3     3 -0.867  0.0386 0.0406  -0.0410      0.118
 4     4 -0.828  0.0402 0.0358  -0.0299      0.110
 5     5 -0.788  0.0424 0.0319  -0.0201      0.105
 6     6 -0.749  0.0455 0.0292  -0.0118      0.103
 7     7 -0.709  0.0497 0.0277  -0.00467     0.104
 8     8 -0.670  0.0554 0.0272   0.00202     0.109
 9     9 -0.630  0.0627 0.0273   0.00923     0.116
10    10 -0.591  0.0720 0.0276   0.0179      0.126
# ℹ 90 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

And we can confirm the point constraint via a plot of the smooth:
draw(m) # or plot(m)



This is an impressively tidy solution, thank you! It looks like 'pc' is specifically for constraining the smooth through zero. I wonder if there is a workaround to establish a non-zero point constraint (e.g. (0, 5)). Nonetheless, this solves my current dilemma - so thank you very much!
